# How to let the compiler deduce the types of my template iterators?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typename

I wrote a function that finds the most common element in any given container (see code below), where the input are two const_iterators for that container. If I call this function however with `findMostFrequent(ivec.begin(), ivec.end())` where `ivec` is a `vector<int>`, the compiler cannot deduce the template arguments. Calling the function with `findMostFrequent< vector<int> >(ivec.begin(), ivec.end())` works fine, but it seems cumbersome. Is there a way to let the compiler find out which template to instantiate?

```
template <typename T> typename T::value_type findMostFrequent(typename T::const_iterator beg, typename T::const_iterator end)
{
    // T is the type of container, T::value_type is the type which is stored in the container
    typename T::size_type current_streak = 0, max_streak = 0;
    T::value_type max_so_far;
    for (T::const_iterator iter = beg; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        current_streak = count(beg, end, *iter);
        if ( current_streak > max_streak )
        {
            max_so_far = *iter;
            max_streak = current_streak;
        }
    }
    return max_so_far;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler can not deduce nested specifiers. "Find me a type that has a nested specifier that is equal to the type that I see as a parameter" is too complicated and often ambiguous to resolve it easily. Instead, try to deduce everything you need to know from the iterators directly:

```
template <typename IteratorType>
typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type
findMostFrequent(IteratorType beg, IteratorType end)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<T>::difference_type current_streak = 0, max_streak = 0;
    typename std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type max_so_far;
    for (IteratorType  iter = beg; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        current_streak = count(beg, end, *iter);
        if ( current_streak > max_streak )
        {
            max_so_far = *iter;
            max_streak = current_streak;
        }
    }
    return max_so_far;
}
```

The reason why you should use `std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type` instead of `T::value_type` is that it enables you to also have these "iterator specifications" for types that do not naturally define them, such as pointers. For example, `T*` is actually a valid iterator for this snippet, but it does not contain a `value_type` typedef/type.

Comment: Thanks! I was unaware of iterator_traits, but I found an excellent explanation here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36530/An-Introduction-to-Iterator-Traits

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by making the function accept an `Iter` template argument and deducing `T` from that using iterator traits (`<iterator>`) - basically the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Because as a template parameter you must use an iterator type. The code below works well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename IterType> 
typename IterType::value_type findMostFrequent(IterType beg, IterType end)
{
    // T is the type of container, T::value_type is the type which is stored in the container
    unsigned int current_streak = 0, max_streak = 0;
    typename IterType::value_type max_so_far;
    for (IterType iter = beg; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        current_streak = count(beg, end, *iter);
        if ( current_streak > max_streak )
        {
            max_so_far = *iter;
            max_streak = current_streak;
        }
    }
    return max_so_far;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        v.push_back(i);

    findMostFrequent(v.begin(), v.end());

    return 0;
}
```

In your code an iterator type don't have any relations to vector and as a result compiler couldn't deduce a template parameter